# SQL pivot in statement

Tags: sql, pivot-table

A question regarding pivot in SQL.
How to use arbitrary names in PIVOT statement in IN?
For example, in statement below in IN I direct specified days of week
Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
But is it possible to use columns values with specification only o n e column name which will be used for IN?
Because some times i don't know which values will be in IN.

```
SELECT * 
      FROM (
            SELECT 
            EmployeeID
           , [WeekDay] = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DateOut)
      FROM dbo.WorkOut
) t
PIVOT (
      COUNT([WeekDay]) 
      FOR [WeekDay] IN (
      Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
      )
) p
```

Comment: Yes, Suppose you have a table with one column containing values : Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday

Then you can use "SELECT column_name from table_name" in IN clause.

Comment: Search for dynamic pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot subquery in pivot. 
We use generated sql sentence for this purpose (in C# program): 
- in the first step run the query and create the comma separated list for the IN part of pivot, 
- in the second step run the pivot.
It runs fine.
If you use only T-SQL, you must create the whole select sentence in a variable, and EXEC it.